# how to get visible products filter by catalog,search magento 2?

Tags: magento2

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->setPageSize(4) // only get 10 products 
    ->setCurPage(1)  // first page (means limit 0,10)
    ->setOrder('entity_id','desc')
    ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', 'catalog_search')
            ->load();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check in Magento admin Visibility attribute have options as below

```
<option data-title="Not Visible Individually" value="1">Not Visible Individually</option>
<option data-title="Catalog" value="2">Catalog</option>
<option data-title="Search" value="3">Search</option>
<option data-title="Catalog, Search" value="4">Catalog, Search</option>
```

We have to pass the value for "catalog, search" and it's 4.

So you should change your code like this

> ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', 4)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->setPageSize(4) // only get 10 products 
             ->setCurPage(1)  // first page (means limit 0,10)
             ->setOrder('entity_id','desc')
             ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', 4)
             ->load();
```